# Confusion in routers

Tags: node.js, express

Firstly i am new in express.js. I just want to know that, when request url contains /api/user/ and request is post then registerUser will be called  but  if request url contains /api/user/ and request is get then 1st protect after that allUsers will be called. am i right???

In server.js i have-->

```
    ......
    ...... 
    app.use('/api/user',userRoutes)
    .....
    .....
```

In userRoutes.js i have -->

```
....
....

 router.route("/").post(registerUser).get(protect,allUsers); //allUser is user searching api endpoint
....
....
```

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: ok means post () and get() will be performed based on request type??

Comment: Yes, express routing is done on paths and [on request method/verb](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.METHOD) (POST, GET, etc)

Comment: It's not clear why you didn't just try the code you have and test it out.  It should work as you have it.  Personally  I'd prefer to write `router.post("/", registerUser);` and `router.get("/", protect, allUsers);` on two separate lines, but what you have will also work.